# Issue related to SSL DLL

Tags: delphi, openssl

Using:

- Delphi Berlin update 2
- Indy version 10.6.2.5341
- Websocket (sgcWebSocketClient, 4.1.7.0 )

We have an application that works in some machines and doesn't in others. The environment is the same, windows 10 recently installed without any other program. Hardware is the same because we have a lot of equal hardwares here.

Well, when we try to connect in a security way, using SSL we get "could not load SSL library". We don´t have OpenSSL installed in any machines (even the machines that works fine)
We have tried the support with the ESEGECE... but didn´t solve until now.

We tried to register the DLLs using regsvr32 but we get some errors and couldn´t register. These are the messages that we get:

> The module "libeay32.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "libeay32.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Or we get:

> The module "C:\Central\libeay32.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified module could not be found

The DLL files are the right one because we copy from ESEGECE examples.

We used `WhichFailedToLoad()` to figure out what is happening, but we get "Failed to load libeay32.dll" message.

We also tried to use `SafeLoadLibrary()` pointing to the place where DLL is located.

We did a test with `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` also but not successful.

`GetLastError()` returns 0.

We found similar questions about this here, tried the solutions as you can see above, but without success.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `regsvr32` to register the OpenSSL DLLs because they are not ActiveX/COM servers.

Assuming you have both `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` together, the most likely reason for `libeay32.dll` to fail to load is because either:

- you are using a 3rd party distribution of `libeay32.dll` or `ssleay32.dll` that have external dependancies on other DLLs, such as the Visual C++ runtime, which you do not have installed. Use a tool like Dependency Walker to verify.

  Try using the OpenSSL DLLs that are available on Indy's Fulgan mirror, as they do not have any external dependencies (except to each other):

  https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/
- your app is 64bit but you are using 32bit versions of `libeay32.dll` or `ssleay32.dll`, or vice versa.