# "Could Not Load SSL Library" error in C++Builder

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, c++builder, indy

This has already been discussed several times, but this time I'm here to ask you because it's the same case.

First of all, the point of the problem is that when using the `Get()` function of `TIdHTTP` on an HTTPS web page, a message appears that the SSL library cannot be loaded.

So I added `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` to `TIdHTTP::IOHandler`, changed the `TIdHTTP::HandleRedirects` property to true, moved the `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` files to the location of the executable file, and it worked normally in C++Builder Berlin.

However, in C++Builder 2007, even if I set it up with the same environment and `Get()` code, the "Could Not Load SSL Library" error appears.

If anyone has experienced similar problems, can you please give me your solution?

Comment: This sounds like something you should take up with the vendor, not stackoverflow.

Comment: @Botje Why? The question is obviously related to programming. He has written a code, and when he runs it an error appears.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742852/issue-related-to-ssl-dll

Comment: @vll the problem was solved on a compiler version that is "only" five years old. C++ builder 2007 is 14 years old.

Comment: @Valtur "*This has already been discussed several times, but this time I'm here to ask you because it's the same case*" - then you really shouldn't be bringing this up again, as this topic has already been discussed in great detail many times before. In any case, are you using the version of Indy that shipped with CB2007? Have you tried upgrading to the latest Indy version yet? What version of the 2 DLLs are you using? What does Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` and `OpenSSLVersion()` functions report when the error occurs?

Comment: @Botje I wanted to find a similar case.
I thought it was an opinion related to development, so I left a message.

Comment: @vll Thank you for agreeing with me. I'm still looking for the problem.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It has not been discussed in detail. Obviously, it was judged to be a problem in another case and left it. Anyway, we are planning to update Indy. OpenSSLVersion() has not been used, and WhichFailToLoad() is SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indyX509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indyX509_getBefore_indyX509_getEsster_not SSL_indyX_set_inde_setEsster_not_after
The function returned this message.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 
Thanks for correcting the question. English is not smooth Because I used a translator, I also knew how to write on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments, you mention that Indy's `WhichFailedToLoad()` function is reporting various `..._indy` functions are missing in the OpenSSL DLLs.  The fact that Indy is looking for those functions means you are using Indy v8 or v9, not v10.  You can verify that by looking at the `gsIdVersion` global variable in the `IdGlobal` unit.

Indy v8 and v9 require *custom-built* OpenSSL **0.9.6** DLLs.  At the time, Indy needed access to various OpenSSL internals that OpenSSL did not expose public access to yet (that was rectified in later OpenSSL versions), so Indy needed to add some custom functions to the DLLs.  You can get those DLLs from the `Archive` folder of [Indy's OpenSSL-Binaries](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries/) repository.

However, Indy v8 and v9 are OLD and no longer supported.  They DO NOT support OpenSSL 1.0.x and later versions. You will have to upgrade to Indy v10, which uses *standard* OpenSSL DLLs, and *officially* supports up to OpenSSL 1.0.2u (support for OpenSSL 1.1.x is [work in progress](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299), but you can try it if you need to use OpenSSL 1.1.x, such as for TLS 1.3).